# Как передавать данные другому устройству?

Tags: php, java, android

На данный момент практикую с `GPS`. На одном устройстве узнаю местоположение, то есть координаты. Но вопрос в том, что не знаю как эти данные отправить другому устройству, чтобы он мог увидеть первое устройство на карте.

Обязательно ли мне нужно изучить `php` или `python` чтобы написать `API` для приема-передачи данных двух устройств или можно и без `веб`, соединять два устройства?

Answer (score 0):

Требуется использовать клиент/серверную архитектуру или клиент/клиент если есть возможность работать в одноранговой сети. Далее выбираете протокол связи и реализуете

Comment: Пожалуйста, опишите решение проблемы более детально, чтобы пользователям было легче понять ваш ответ. Для редактирования ответа, нажмите [Edit]. Так же можете ознакомиться с советами о том, [как написать хороший ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). - [Из очереди проверок](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/148610)